# Set _utmz cookie for Direct Visits?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, utm

It is my understanding that Direct Visits do not rewrite _utmz cookies in Google Analytics, as these visits are not "campaigns" or generated by an external source.  However, I still want to track users that come to my site on subsequent visits by Direct means. Is there a way to set a utmz cookie for Direct Visits (only on direct visits) via some extra code snippet?  Or is this something that maybe should be done via a custom variable?

I know GA now has the "multi-channel" funnel, but it's not perfect by any means.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there is a referer (e.g. via javascript's document.referrer) and if there is none pass some custom utm parameters (utm_source and utm_medium) to a virtual url (second parameter to the trackPageview method) - if there is no referer it's a direct visit (with some margin of error since some UAs do not send referers).

However I'm not quite certain want you are trying to accomplish - if you want to examine direct visitors you could simply create a custom segment with "source=(direct)".

If you want to track visitors who first arrive as direct visitors and then return via another source you could create a custom variable (again depending on the referer) and create a custom segment based on that. The variable needs to be created at visitor scope (last parameter to the _setCustomVar method) so it persists as long as the google cookie is not deleted by the visitor (and thus is set for returning visitors).

Not perfect ideas by any means but maybe they point you into the right direction....

Answer (score 0):

traffic source "(direct) / (none)" is always used when HTTP referrer is empty, which might not alway be due direct visit to your site. However, there is a imperfect solution to this, presuming that vast majority of direct visits are landing on your homepage "/", you can use simple javascript, that pushes utm_source and utm_medium values when HTTP referrer is empty and user is landing on your homepage.